# Printing an upside down right triangle in Python 3.7

Tags: python

I have been trying to print an upside down right triangle in Python 3.7. This is the code I wrote:

```
n=4
for i in range (0, n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        print("*", end="")
        n-=1
    print()
```

According to what I understood about loops, the nested for loop should iterate `n` times while the outer for loop iterates once. Following that logic, the column loop should print four asterisks, then one less each time the loop turns because the value of `n` reduces by one.

But the output I get is this:

```
****
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: I know and understand the alternative ways of solving this problem. It's just that I don't get why this particular piece of code is not working.

Comment: You're modifying `n` in the inner loop, so the outer loop only runs once.

Comment: But shouldn't the outer loop run 4 times even if I'm not modifying n in the outer loop?

Comment: After the first inner loop, `n` is 0. When you run the next outer loops, you run `for j in range(0, 0):`, which is an empty range, so the inner loop won't be entered even once.

Comment: Oops, you're right there.  The outer loop runs four times, but the inner loop only runs the first time, when `n > 0`.

Comment: That was super helpful, tysm!

Answer (score 3):

You will be better off using the `*` operator to build your string.

```
n = 4
for i in range(n):
    print('*' * (n-i))
```

Output:

```
****
*** 
**
*
```